# Building my own sty for beamer

Tags: beamer

I am trying to build my own `sty` for beamer from the Berlin theme. I want to add logos to the footers of my slides. I am a little confused on how to do this with the sty. I don't know where should I put the `logo` tag. Any help?

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: /Users/joseph/Documents/LaTeX/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeBerlin.sty,v d02a7cf4d8ae 2010/06/17 09:11:41 rivanvx $

 \DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
 \ProcessOptionsBeamer

 \mode<presentation>

 \useoutertheme[footline=authorinstitutetitle]{miniframes}
 \usecolortheme{whale}
 \usecolortheme{orchid}
 \useinnertheme{rectangles}

 \setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}
 \logo{%
   \makebox[0.95\paperwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{cern_logo_white.jpg}%
   \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{ntua-logo.jpg}%
    DEF
   }%
  }

  \mode
  <all>
```

Comment: Do you really need to create your own beamer style, instead of just copy & paste the relevant pars of an existing talk?

Comment: Welcome! So you've defined your logo using the `\logo` command. What is the question exactly?

Comment: Probably you want to put the logo in the `footline` template rather than using the `\logo` command. What you have seems to work fine as a logo in Beamer's sense, so I assume you don't want a logo like that.

Comment: @cfr How I put the logo in the footline?

Comment: @vonbrand I don't know if I need to create my own style. I just want to put the logo in the footline.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image: double trouble]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.sty}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\def\beamer@theme@footline@doubletrouble{% modified from tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterthememiniframes.sty
  \defbeamertemplate*{footline}{miniframes theme}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3.625ex,dp=0ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\includegraphics[height=3.0625ex,width=10mm,keepaspectratio]{\doubletrouble@logo@left}\quad
        \raisebox{.375ex}{\doubletrouble@text@left}}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\includegraphics[height=3.0625ex,width=10mm,keepaspectratio]{\doubletrouble@logo@right}\quad
        \raisebox{.375ex}{\doubletrouble@text@right}}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
}

\mode<presentation>

\useoutertheme[footline=doubletrouble]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\newcommand*\doubletrouble@logo@left{example-image-a}
\newcommand*\doubletrouble@logo@right{example-image-b}
\newcommand\doubletrouble@text@left{}
\newcommand\doubletrouble@text@right{}
\newcommand*\logoleft[1]{\renewcommand*\doubletrouble@logo@left{#1}}
\newcommand*\logoright[1]{\renewcommand*\doubletrouble@logo@right{#1}}
\newcommand\logotextleft[1]{\renewcommand\doubletrouble@text@left{#1}}
\newcommand\logotextright[1]{\renewcommand\doubletrouble@text@right{#1}}

\mode
<all>
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{\jobname}
\logoleft{tiger}
\logoright{cath}
\logotextright{DEF}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
some text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your example, but I am full of errors. 

      ! Undefined control sequence.
      <argument> \doubletrouble@logo@left                                 
      l.51 \begin{document}                  
      The control sequence at the end of the top line
      of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
      misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
      spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
      and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
      ! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.

Your example goes into a single latex file?

Comment: @xeon123 It works fine here. It is a single file just for convenience in making the example. The bit in the `filecontents` environment gets written to `\jobname.sty` where `\jobname` is typically the name of your `.tex` file, minus the extension. This then gets loaded by the `\usepackage{}` line. But if you were to use this, you'd just put the package code in your `.sty` file in the usual way.  Does my example exactly as written give you an error?

Comment: Yes, maybe because I named the text file workshop.tex and not jobname.tex

Comment: Yes, it didn't work becaus I have named the file workshop.tex. Now, with jobname.tex works. Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what you name the `.tex` file. If you call it `squigglydoo.tex`, `\jobname` will, by default, be `squigglydoo`.